# Adding multiple checkboxes into one database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

Firstly I have had a look at other questions on stackoverflow which relate to this but I still don't understand how to do it which is why I am asking this question so please don't neg me for asking a duplicate question.

I am trying to link together A parent and its Children for my website. The parent firstly adds the names of their children and then creates a news item about the children. That is all fine except I am struggling to complete the section where the user ticks which children were involved in that news item and then store those childrens names in my database.

Currently the code only enters the childID of the last child ticked in the form. Do I need a link table

Code so far:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","****");
if (isset($_POST['NewsDate'])&&isset($_POST['NewsDescription'])&&isset($_POST['Children'])){

$NewsDate= $_POST['NewsDate'];
$NewsDescription= $_POST['NewsDescription'];
$Children = $_POST['Children'];

if (!empty($NewsDate)&&!empty($NewsDescription)&&!empty($Children)){

$sql="INSERT INTO News (NewsDate, NewsDescription, Children, AccountID)
 VALUES('$NewsDate','$NewsDescription','$Children','".$_SESSION['user_id']."')";

 mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 /* commit transaction */
if (!mysqli_commit($con)) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}
} else {
       echo'All fields are required';
      }
}
/* close connection */

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<form action="addnews.php" method="post">
  <p>News Date:       <br/>  <input type="text" name="NewsDate" id="datepicker"/></p>
  <p>News Description (max 255 characters):<br><textarea name="NewsDescription" rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="255"></textarea></p> 
  <p>Children Involved: <br> 

  <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","pytsuemg_brodie","brodie","pytsuemg_brodie");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Child WHERE `AccountID`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {

    echo $row['Firstname'] . " " . $row['Surname']; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Children" value=" <? echo $row['ChildID']; ?>" />
    <?
}

?>
 </p>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And since you haven't shown your form or what's in `$_POST['Children']`, we can't really help you.

Comment: the form is included at the bottom of the code

Comment: Ok. your checkbox name is incorrect. ALL of your checkboxes will have the same name, meaning the LAST one checked is the one whose value will show up in $_POST. You'd need to php's array notation, `name="Children[]"` to get PHP to create an array of values. Then you'll have to mod your query to handle that array.

Comment: Ok thanks how would I go about changing my query to fit an array. I've never worked with arrays before in PHP so its all new to me

Comment: you start by normalizing your db table and put the children info into a separate table. you do NOT want to store your child IDs in a csv format in a single field. then it's just a matter of looping on $_POST['Children'] and inserting each value into that new child table.